# Initialize number by NULL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

What is the difference between **initializing a number type variable** by `null` and by `Zero` in PLSQL?
example-

```
l_person_id     NUMBER :=NULL;
```

and

```
l_person_id     NUMBER :=0;
```

Does this effect anywhere in a code?

Comment: `NULL` is the absence of a value. `NULL` is not comparable to any other value, even itself. Perhaps you should [read up on `NULL`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)).

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference.

If you have comparison operations in your code then you can get unexpected behaviour:

```
5 > l_person_id_null -- false
5 > l_person_id_0    -- true
```

Also, with `NULL` you'll have to use `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` operators instead of `=`.